# Derivative of $f(0)=0$

Tags: derivatives

Why is the derivative of $f(x) = x-(x^2-2x)$ not defined at $x= 0$?

For a function $f(x) = x-|x^2-2x|$, the differentiation is possible when is broken into a piece wise function. i.e.

$$f(x) =\begin{cases}x-(x^2-2x)&x^2-2x\ge0\\
       x+(x^2-2x)&x^2-2x < 0\end{cases}$$

$$f'(x)=\begin{cases}1-(2x-2)&x^2-2x > 0\\ 
        1+(2x-2)&x^2-2x < 0\end{cases}$$

The derivative at $x=0$ is not defined. Why? Please explain.

Comment: Have you checked to see if th right- and left -e expressions agree at $x=0$?

Comment: The derivative of the function $f$ defined by $f(x) = x - (x^2 - 2x)$ *is* defined at $x=0$, but that's not what the rest of your question is asking. Have you tried computing the derivative at $x=0$? You could go all the way back to the limit definition of derivative if you need to.

Comment: The function is $f(x)=x-|x^2-2x|$??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be small positive. Then $x^2-2x$ is negative, so $x-|x^2-2x|=x-(2x-x^2)=-x+x^2$.

Let $x$ be negative. Then $x^2-2x$ is positive, so $x-|x^2-2x|=x-(x^2-2x)=3x-x^2$.

So if $h$ is small positive, then $\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=-1+h$.

If $h$ is negative, then $\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=3-h$.

Thus the limit of $\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}$ as $h$ approaches $0$ from the right is $-1$.

The limit of $\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}$ as $h$ approaches $0$ from the left is $3$.

It follows that $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}$ does not exist.

**Remark:** It might be useful to have software graph the function, so that you can see the "kink" at $x=0$. This example is an more complicated version of the probably familiar fact that the function $g(x)=|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: Thank you. Because the limit at zero is two sided, the derivative at zero does not exist.

Comment: You are right, for the derivative to exist the limit of the "difference quotient" must exist. So if the limits from the right and from the left are *different*, the "full" limit does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

$$f'(0)=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x-|x^2-2x|}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x-|x(x-2)|}{x} $$
If $x \to 0^+$ then $x(x-2)<0$:
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{x-|x(x-2)|}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{x+x(x-2)}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}1+(x-2)=-1$$

If $x \to 0^-$ then $x(x-2)>0$:
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{x-|x(x-2)|}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{x-x(x-2)}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}1-(x-2)=3$$
Then 
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x-|x(x-2)|}{x}=f'(0)$$ does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the way you were taught derivatives. There is a theorem which states that the derivative of $f(g(x))$ is $f'(g(x)) g'(x)$ in every point where both $f$ and $g$ are differentiable. In your case you have $g(x)=x^2-2x$ and $f(y) = |y|$ which is differentiable for $y\neq 0$ and from the theorem you find that your function is differentiable for $x\neq 0$ and $x\neq 2$. But the theorem tells you nothing in the case that the assumptions are not satisfied. When $g(x)=0$ i.e. for $x=0$ and $x=2$ you should use the definition of derivative and check if the limits exists and are finite:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(g(x+h))-f(g(x))}{h},\qquad
\lim_{x\to 2} \frac{f(g(x+h))-f(g(x))}{h}
$$

If you look at the function $|x^2-2x|$ as a function defined *piecewise* you are using another theorem which tells you that the derivative of a function in a point $x$ only depend on the values of $f$ in a neighbourhood of $x$. So if you have a function defined piecewise as:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} g(x)\text{ if } x \in I\\
        h(x) \text{ if } x \in J
\end{cases}
$$
and if $g$ and $h$ are differentiable, you can conclude that $f$ is differentiable in the *interior* of $I$ and in the interior of $J$. Again this tells you nothing about the points in the boundary of $I$ or $J$. In such points you need, again, to apply the definition of derivative.

Actually there is a positive result which you can use to avoid to check the limit of the incremental ratio. By l'Hopital theorem one can show that if a function $f$ is continuous in a point $x_0$ and if it is differentiable in a neighbourhood of $x_0$ and if $f'(x)\to \ell$ as $x\to x_0$, then $f$ is differentiable in $x_0$ and $f'(x_0)=\ell$.